# How do I disable joystick input?

Tags: input, joystick

The file `/dev/input/js0` related to joysticks is giving me some problems in games.

I just renamed the file and everything went to normal.
So, how do I disable joystick input? I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Ok, my microsoft keyboard is recognized as a joystick!!!!? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If your actual issue is that your Microsoft keyboard gets recognized as a joystick, [you](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28912) [are](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37982) [not](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/390959) [alone](https://ryort.wordpress.com/2011/12/04/udev-and-the-microsoft-digital-media-keyboard-3000-wha/), [it](https://forum.manjaro.org/index.php?topic=15275.msg144519#msg144519) [affects](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=190485) [several](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=142469) [people](http://steamcommunity.com/app/286690/discussions/0/619573787388839852/).

My solution for that is to download [this file](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/denilsonsa/978f1d842cf5430f57f6/raw) and save it as `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-these-are-not-joysticks.rules`. You can run this command on a terminal:

```
sudo curl -o /etc/udev/rules.d/51-these-are-not-joysticks.rules \ 
  https://gist.githubusercontent.com/denilsonsa/978f1d842cf5430f57f6/raw
```

Link to my GitHub Gist containing the file: https://gist.github.com/denilsonsa/978f1d842cf5430f57f6

---

[years later]

After many contributions, that little file grew and moved from that GitHub Gist to a full GitHub repository: https://github.com/denilsonsa/udev-joystick-blacklist, and many distros started incorporating that workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You should see your joystick number first... so open a terminal and run `xinput list` and look to your joystick number and replace its number (instead of the 10) in the example below.

```
#!/bin/bash
id=xinput list | grep "↳ DragonRise Inc. Generic USB Joystick id=10" | cut -c58-59
props_mouse=xinput list-props 10 | grep "Generate Mouse Events (" | cut -c25-27
props_teclado=xinput list-props 10 | grep "Generate Key Events (" | cut -c23-25
xinput set-prop 10 $props_mouse 0
xinput set-prop 10 $props_teclado 0
```

Save the above into a file like `~/disable_joystick.sh` and then run `chmod +x ~/disable_joystick.sh`.

You can now run `~/disable_joystick.sh` and it should block your device from generating mouse and keyboard events in X.