# Cideko Air Keyboard being recognised as a joystick (22.04)

Tags: usb, keyboard

After a few years of problem-free use, my Cideko air keyboard is being recognised as a joystick.  It seemed to randomly stop working and the only thing I've been able to do to get it working is to fire up the joystick calibration screen and leave it running in the background.

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS"
```

Output of lsusb is:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 20e8:5861 Cideko Inc. AK08 Device
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 046d:0825 Logitech, Inc. Webcam C270
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05e3:070e Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Card Reader
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 15c2:0036 SoundGraph Inc. LC16M VFD Display/IR Receiver
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

If I list /dev/input/by-id/ :

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  7 09:43 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-event-kbd -> ../event2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  7 09:43 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-event-if03 -> ../event5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  7 09:43 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if01-mouse -> ../mouse0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  7 09:43 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if02-event-joystick -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  7 09:43 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if01-event-mouse -> ../event3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  6 Sep  7 09:43 usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if02-joystick -> ../js0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  7 09:43 usb-15c2_0036-mouse -> ../mouse2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  9 Sep  7 09:43 usb-15c2_0036-event-mouse -> ../event8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Sep  7 09:43 usb-046d_0825_7CD77CA0-event-if00 -> ../event10
```

I tried the fix by [Denilson Sá Maia](https://askubuntu.com/users/8668/denilson-s%C3%A1-maia) mentioned here:
[How do I disable joystick input?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173376/how-do-i-disable-joystick-input)

which led me to the latest GitHub version here:
https://github.com/denilsonsa/udev-joystick-blacklist

Then appended my own Vendor/Product to his file:

```
...
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="20e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5861", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}=="?*", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}=""
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="20e8", ATTRS{idProduct}=="5861", KERNEL=="js[0-9]*", MODE="0000", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}=""
...
```

The first option seems to have no effect at all. The second option removes it so it's not usable (even with my workaround).

Any idea how to get it working as a keyboard again?

Answer (score 1):

Without having the device, it's hard to know. And the company doesn't even exist anymore, as their website is gone [since 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160412151519/http://www.cideko.com/product.php?cat_id=20): http://www.cideko.com/

I can't find any relevant mention of the vendor id `20e8` in the [linux kernel source-code](https://github.com/torvalds/linux), nor in [libinput source-code](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libinput/libinput).

[There aren't any reports of that device at linux-hardware.org](https://linux-hardware.org/?view=search&vendorid=20e8) either. It sounds like you are one of the very few people who bought that device, and possibly the only one who still uses it and uses it on Linux.

Since you said it worked problem-free for years, I would suggest you trying your device on different distros or different distro versions. You can use [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) to load a bunch of ISO files from different distros on a bootable USB drive, so you can quickly test them. Maybe also test it on different computers, if you have access to those. Try to take note (possibly in a spreadsheet) of:

- Distro name
- Distro version
- Linux kernel version (`uname -rv`)
- libinput version
- Does it work initially?
- Does it keep working after a while?
- Does it work while doing joystick calibration?
- Does it work while some app is using the joystick?

Try also to pay attention to kernel messages: `sudo dmesg -H -w`

---

I guess the keyboard/mouse functionality will also work if any app or game starts using the joystick, like when opening [this test page](https://greggman.github.io/html5-gamepad-test/) or [this test app](https://github.com/denilsonsa/pygame-joystick-test). (I guess it's not just when the joystick calibration happens.)

I would guess some power-saving feature is putting your USB receiver in some low-energy state that makes it sleep and thus unable to receive data from the device. That could explain why any device opening/reading/interacting with the joystick makes the receiver wake up and work properly. But this is just a wild guess. It could be a "recent" change to Linux kernel drivers, or to libinput, or something else entirely.

Good luck! Hopefully with these steps you can narrow down the issue. And please remember to post your results here (as a comment or as another answer).

Answer (score 0):

I revisited this, and realised the quick and dirty hack is to run crontab -e and paste in:

```
@reboot nohup cat /dev/input/by-id/usb-Cideko_Inc._AK08_Device-if02-event-joystick </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This has the same effect as running the joystick config screen on the desktop, but it starts it every time the machine boots up and runs in the background.